# Can I learn Tiger Blade after the events in Zaphias?

Tags: tales-of-vesperia

In order to obtain Tiger Blade, you have to do this:

**After you get the boat, go to  the Royal Quarter in Zaphias and speak to a man named Shel.  Speak to him again on the street to the west.  After speaking to him the second time, go down to the Public Quarter and speak to a woman on a bench to learn Tiger Blade.**

Zaphias and the lower quarter are involved in the main story line:

> When Estelle is kidnapped and forced to use her powers to take over the city

Can you still get Tiger Blade after this situation has been dealt with?